# How to echo json as string instead of bytes

Tags: python, json

I'm trying to write a json to a file:

```
echo '{ "date":"2020-02-10 10:09:34" }' > file.json
```

However, when I read it I need to decode it from bytes to string. I want to write it so that there is no decoding needed when reading it.

This is how I'm reading it in python:

```
with open("file.json", "rb") as f: config_file = json.loads(f.read())
```

Answer (score 3):

The python [open()](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_open.asp) function has two parameters, the first is the file to be opened and the second is the mode in which to open it.   For mode you have the following options:

> A string, define which mode you want to open the file in: "r" - Read -
> Default value. Opens a file for reading, error if the file does not
> exist
>
> "a" - Append - Opens a file for appending, creates the file if it does
> not exist
>
> "w" - Write - Opens a file for writing, creates the file if it does
> not exist
>
> "x" - Create - Creates the specified file, returns an error if the
> file exist
>
> In addition you can specify if the file should be handled as binary or
> text mode
>
> "t" - Text - Default value. Text mode
>
> "b" - Binary - Binary mode (e.g. images)

Since you have specified the `b` option the file is being opened in binary mode which is not what you want for a text file.  You can either change the `b` to `t` for text mode or just drop the `b` altogether as text mode is default.